# Detecet if a facebook like button as been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Hey so i'm looking for a way to detect if the facebook like button on my site has been clicked without using the api.

i thought about detecting it by the like box color but i have no idea on how to use iframe with JS/JQ i will realy appreciate if u can help me to get it to work so i can just inside to an if statement.

so it will look like that
if (liked) than
   code...

this is my like box code:

```
<div id="fb-root">&nbsp;</div>
<p>
<script>// <![CDATA[
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/uefachampionsleague/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">&nbsp;</div>
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just register a `click` listener? If you did you would also receive an event, in addition to the FB like code, when the user clicks on this.

Comment: Yea i know but i cant use it for my project but thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can not detect anything like color, because the Like button runs in an iframe that has its content loaded from a different domain, and therefor the Same Origin Policy prevents any JS access.